# How to resolve jquery children method alert error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

what's the problem here? When I run this code I get undefined error

```
<div>
    <span>ali</span>
    <span>veli</span>
    <span>deli</span>
</div>

<script>
    var x = $("div").children();
    alert(x[0].text);
</script>
```

Comment: well there is no text property in DOM element so it is undefined. So if the undefined error is not an error but the alert showing "undefined". Unclear why you are not just using jQuery. `x.eq(0).text()` with DOM `x[0].textContent`

Answer (score 0):

You get `undefined` because there is no HTML DOM property named `text`. Maybe you wanted to use [`innerText`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) property, *e.g.*:

```js
var x = $("div").children();
alert(x[0].innerText);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>ali</span>
  <span>veli</span>
  <span>deli</span>
</div>
```